# OpenSL: What's causing static when loading wav files through AAsset_read?

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, opensl

I'm working on a native android project and trying to use OpenSL to play some audio effects. Working from the native audio sample project VisualGDB provides, I've written the code posted below.

Near the end, you can see I have commented a line that stores the contents of a variable called hello in the buffer to the destination. hello comes from the sample project, and contains about 700 lines of character bytes like this:

"\x02\x00\x01\x00\xff\xff\x09\x00\x0c\x00\x10\x00\x07\x00\x07\x00"

which make an audio file of someone saying "hello". When reading that byte data into the stream, my code works fine and I hear "hello" when I run the application. When I read from wav file to play the asset I want, however, I only hear static. The size of the data buffer is the same as the size of the file, so it appears it's being read in properly. The static plays for the duration of the wav file (or very close to it).

I really know nothing about data formats or audio programming. I've tried tweaking the format_pcm variables some with different enum values, but had no success. Using a tool called GSpot I found on The Internet, I know the following about the audio file I'm trying to play:

File Size: 557 KB (570,503 bytes) (this is the same size as the data buffer 
AAsset_read returns

Codec: PCM Audio

Sample rate: 48000Hz

Bit rate: 1152 kb/s

Channels: 1

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
SLDataLocator_AndroidSimpleBufferQueue loc_bufq = { SL_DATALOCATOR_ANDROIDSIMPLEBUFFERQUEUE, 1 };
SLDataFormat_PCM format_pcm;
format_pcm.formatType = SL_DATAFORMAT_PCM;
format_pcm.numChannels = 1;
format_pcm.samplesPerSec = SL_SAMPLINGRATE_48;// SL_SAMPLINGRATE_8;
format_pcm.bitsPerSample = SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_8; // SL_PCMSAMPLEFORMAT_FIXED_16;
format_pcm.containerSize = 16;
format_pcm.channelMask = SL_SPEAKER_FRONT_CENTER;
format_pcm.endianness = SL_BYTEORDER_LITTLEENDIAN;

SLDataSource audioSrc = { &loc_bufq, &format_pcm };

// configure audio sink
SLDataLocator_OutputMix loc_outmix = { SL_DATALOCATOR_OUTPUTMIX, manager->GetOutputMixObject() };
SLDataSink audioSnk = { &loc_outmix, NULL };

//create audio player
const SLInterfaceID ids[3] = { SL_IID_BUFFERQUEUE, SL_IID_EFFECTSEND, SL_IID_VOLUME };
const SLboolean req[3] = { SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE };

SLEngineItf engineEngine = manager->GetEngine();
result = (*engineEngine)->CreateAudioPlayer(engineEngine, &bqPlayerObject, &audioSrc, &audioSnk,
    3, ids, req);

// realize the player
result = (*bqPlayerObject)->Realize(bqPlayerObject, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);

// get the play interface
result = (*bqPlayerObject)->GetInterface(bqPlayerObject, SL_IID_PLAY, &bqPlayerPlay);

// get the buffer queue interface
result = (*bqPlayerObject)->GetInterface(bqPlayerObject, SL_IID_BUFFERQUEUE,
    &bqPlayerBufferQueue);

// register callback on the buffer queue
result = (*bqPlayerBufferQueue)->RegisterCallback(bqPlayerBufferQueue, bqPlayerCallback, NULL);

// get the effect send interface
result = (*bqPlayerObject)->GetInterface(bqPlayerObject, SL_IID_EFFECTSEND,
    &bqPlayerEffectSend);

// get the volume interface
result = (*bqPlayerObject)->GetInterface(bqPlayerObject, SL_IID_VOLUME, &bqPlayerVolume);

// set the player's state to playing
result = (*bqPlayerPlay)->SetPlayState(bqPlayerPlay, SL_PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);

uint8* pOutBytes = nullptr;
uint32 outSize = 0;
result = MyFileManager::GetInstance()->OpenFile(m_strAbsolutePath, (void**)&pOutBytes, &outSize, true);
const char* filename = m_strAbsolutePath->GetUTF8String();
result = (*bqPlayerBufferQueue)->Enqueue(bqPlayerBufferQueue, pOutBytes, outSize);
// result = (*bqPlayerBufferQueue)->Enqueue(bqPlayerBufferQueue, hello, sizeof(hello));
if (SL_RESULT_SUCCESS != result) {
    return JNI_FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Several things were to blame. The format of the wave files I was testing with was not what the specification described. There seemed to be a lot of empty data after the first chunk of header data. Also, the buffer that needs to be passed to the queue needs to be a char* of just the wav data, not the header. I'd wrongly assumed the queue parsed the header out.